Talend file name with year validation
Talend,  From the list of files fetched by tFileList , I need to check files belongs to this year and move to one location. Files outside this year, need to move to another location
How to check the file name contains  this year (TestfineName1_20240101.txt) or not
(!context.File_Name.contains("context.Cycle_Year"))
